# Connection between Weyl fermions and Fermi arcs

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, material-science, fermions

I am looking for references (such as research or review articles) that discuss the theoretical origin of [Fermi arcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_arc) in certain materials and their connection to Weyl fermion physics. In particular, how do Fermi arcs in systems with Weyl fermions differ from those that don't have Weyl fermions? I know that Fermi arcs come about from a breaking of either time-reversal or parity symmetry, but where does the Weyl physics come in? Any references or explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of a Weyl point as a magnetic monopole in the Berry connection, and the Fermi arc represents the (homology class of the) Dirac string connecting these two monopoles. Fermi arcs are impossible to realize in intrinsicly 2d band structures because bands are not allowed to end (but they are allowed to "flow" into the bulk, in the sense of anomaly in-flow). Weyl physics appears at the monopoles because of the famous correlary of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem that monopoles coupled to Dirac fermions trap chiral zero modes.

[These slides (pdf)](http://wwwphy.princeton.edu/~haldane/talks/WPI-MANA_topology.pdf) by Haldane are very nice. Also check out the [original article](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.83.205101) by Wan, Turner, Vishwanath, and Savrasov, it's very nice as well.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the Fermi surface of a 3D system will "transform" into a Fermi arc if I introduce Weyl points in the material? i.e., is there a way to smoothly go from Fermi surface to Fermi arc in some condensed matter system by tuning a parameter?

Comment: If you first make a Dirac point in the 3D band structure by getting two bands to touch, you can then break T or I and separate it into two inverse Weyl points connected by a Fermi arc. The only thing you can't do is introduce a chiral number of Weyl points, since there is a quantized anomaly given by a (chiral) 4+1D Chern-Simons theory of the form indicated by the index theorem: $F^3 + FR^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have one other question: if I were to separate the Dirac point into two inverse Weyl points connect by a Fermi arc, and then bring the Weyl points together at another point on the 3D material's surface, will I form a closed Fermi surface? That is, there a smooth transition from Fermi arc to Fermi surface as I bring the separate Weyl points together?

Comment: @JoshuahHeath I'm not sure I understand. I would imagine then you are left with a closed fermi "arc", ie. an extra boundary band, not a bulk band.